# Topological covers $\mathbb{CP}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have the $\mathbb{C}$-variety $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$. When we analytify this variety we get $\mathbb{CP}^1$. The question is: suppose we have a morphism $f : \mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ such that the analytification of this morphism $f^{an}:\mathbb{CP}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^1$ is a topological cover of degree $d$. What values of $d$ can we then have?

My attempt: since $f$ is a morphism, the pullback of regular functions should again be regular, but since $O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathbb{P}^1)=\mathbb{C}$ we see that $f^*$ is just the identity map $O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathbb{P}^1)\rightarrow O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathbb{P}^1)$. I actually don't know if this is useful, and I don't know how to continue. I need some explanation. Thanks.

Comment: It's true that global functions are constants, and that pullbacks of constants are constant, but this won't be enough because it's true for any projective variety at all. Do you know the Riemann Hurwitz formula ? (If not, you can prove it yourself topologically -- what is your definition of "degree" in the topological category ?)

Comment: @hunter Yes, I know about the Riemann Hurwitz formula: it says that (in this example) that if $f:\mathbb{CP}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^1$ is a ramified covering, then $\chi(\mathbb{CP}^1)=d\chi (\mathbb{CP}^1)+(1-d)|R|$ where $R$ is the set of point where the map is 1 to 1. As our map is a topological cover, we have $R$ is empty so the only possibility should then be $d=1$?

Comment: Your computation is right. Indeed, $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is simply connected.

Comment: @DanieleA your argument is better than mine :-) no need for riemann hurwitz, regular maps, etc. etc.: just, no non-trivial  covers of the sphere!

Comment: I think the Riemann-Hurwitz argument is also very useful: for example you can use it in reverse to show that $\mathbb{CP}^1$ has no nontrivial topological covering of finite degree. Or that there are no nonconstant morphism from a curve to another of smaller genus.